# Gerrit website doesn't show command

Tags: gerrit

Gerrit always show clone command like this :

[image]

The gerrit server i build view like this :

[image]

Is any plugin should be installed ? I already install download-commands plugin.

this is my gerrit.config file:

```
[gerrit]
    basePath = git
    serverId = 8f64957d-327a-4099-93ad-dc3f6fb598fa
    canonicalWebUrl = http://192.168.1.188:8090
[database]
    type = h2
    database = /Users/wxkmac/Documents/gerrit/db/ReviewDB
[auth]
    type = HTTP
    #httpHeader = SM_USER
[receive]
    enableSignedPush = false
[sendemail]
    smtpServer = smtp.163.com  
    smtpServerPort = 465  
    smtpEncryption = ssl  
    smtpUser = xxx@163.com  
    smtpPass = xxxx  
    sslVerify = false  
    from=CodeReview<xxx@163.com>  
[container]
    user = xxx
    javaHome = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
[sshd]
    listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = proxy-http://192.168.1.188:7788/
[cache]
    directory = cache
[download]
  command = checkout
  command = cherry_pick
  command = pull
  command = format_patch
  scheme = ssh
  scheme = http
  scheme = anon_http
  scheme = anon_git
  scheme = repo_download
```

Answer (score 1):

Some itens to check:

1) Make sure the donwloads-commands plugin is installed and running without issues

Check Plugins > installed

Check GERRIT-SITE/plugins

Restart Gerrit and check GERRIT-SITE/logs

2) Make sure you have set the download options in GERRIT-SITE/etc/gerrit.config

```
[download]
    scheme = https
```

3) I think, in your case, you should set the sshd.advertisedAddress option

See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#sshd.advertisedAddress).

Comment: Yes,i already set this after i install `download-commands`plugin.